# Read TSQL variable from Temp Table

Tags: t-sql

I am hacking around trying to write a script to restore a backup from a known folder location.  The location will only ever contain one backup file.  I have come up with this so far, but I don't know how to get the value from the temp table into the `restore database` command.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempFileTable (FName VARCHAR(8000),Depth INTEGER, Files INTEGER)

INSERT INTO #tempFileTable
EXEC xp_dirtree 'S:\', 1, 1

SELECT TOP 1 FName FROM #tempFileTable

DROP TABLE #tempFileTable

DECLARE @DBName varchar(255) = 'DatabaseName'

RESTORE DATABASE @DBName FROM  DISK = ??? WITH  FILE = 1

GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempFileTable (FName VARCHAR(8000),Depth INTEGER, Files INTEGER)

INSERT INTO #tempFileTable
EXEC xp_dirtree 'D:\Test1', 1, 1

SELECT TOP 1 Fname FROM #tempFileTable;

DECLARE @DBName varchar(255) = 'Test'

select 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @DBName + ' FROM  DISK = D:\Test1\' + fname +  ' WITH  FILE = 1' 
from #tempFileTable

DROP TABLE #tempFileTable

GO
```

Output:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Test FROM  DISK = D:\Test1\ReportServer.bak WITH  FILE = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like :

```
declare @file varchar(50)
declare @DBName varchar(50)
declare @sql varchar(200)

CREATE TABLE #tempFileTable (FName VARCHAR(8000),Depth INTEGER, Files INTEGER)

INSERT INTO #tempFileTable
EXEC xp_dirtree 'D:\', 1, 1

select @file = FName
from #tempFileTable

set @DBName = 'MyDB'

set @sql = 'RESTORE DATABASE '+@DBName+' FROM  DISK = ''D:\'+@file+''' WITH  FILE = 1'

print @sql
```

Comment: ...and then there is `sp_executesql`, which will execute the sql string passed in, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188001%28v=sql.120%29.aspx